# How to remove Spray Foam Cleaner stain from concrete

Tags: concrete, spray-foam

I have leaked a liquid mix of Spray Foam Sealant Dispensing Gun Cleaner and orange spray foam from a garbage bag onto a concrete floor, leaving an orange stain.

What's the easiest way to remove the colored stain?

Comment: Since it is outside you can try gasoline

Comment: @Ruskes "floor" indicates to me an indoor slab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grind it off. Or paint over it. Solvents don't work once the stuff has cured.

Comment: would the stuff that's mixed with the sealant cleaner still "cure"

Comment: Probably. Just slower and soaking in more.

Comment: The cleaner evaporates rapidly, so "mixed with the cleaner" is a very temporary situation. Once the product has cured, the cleaner won't touch it, and I doubt gasoline would either. Uncured, gasoline would work, but acetone (which is mostly what the cleaner is) works fine with less hazard.

Comment: Take a torch to it, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try power sprayer, rent it or buy it.

I use gasoline to wash it off but that is no no for many